# VisualStudio で作成してインストールしたアプリが起動しない

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wpf

VisualStudio Ver 17.4.2　で作成したWPFアプリを作成して
Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects 2022　拡張機能で
インストーラーを作成してインストールしてショートカット/実際の実行ファイル両方で
起動しようとしましたが起動しませんでした。

ビルドしたときに作成される..Project\Project\bin\Release\net6.0-windows\Project.exeファイルでは
実行すると正常に起動します。

アプリの仕様
ターゲットフレームワーク：　.NET6.0
ターゲットOS：Windows
ターゲットOS：バージョン7.0
Nugetパッケージ
EnityFrameworkCore.Design 6.0.13
EntityFrameworkCore.sqlserver 6.0.13
Prism.Wpf 8.1.97
RectiveProperty.Wpf 9.0.0-pre202301080724

【インストーラー作成時】
プロジェクト出力種類を

---

・項目の公開
・PublishItemsOutputGroup
をそれぞれ選択して作成してインストールして実行ファイルをダブルクリックしたときの挙動

一度カーソルがロード(水色輪)⇒やじるし⇒ロード(水色輪)⇒やじるしと変化してその後
何も起こらなくなる

---

・プライマリ出力
をそれぞれ選択して作成してインストールして実行ファイルをダブルクリックしたときの挙動

システムファイル (.dll) を開こうとしています と表示されて開くアプリ選択となるが
起動させることはできませんでした。

---

以上のような問題が発生しておりまして作業が止まってしまいました。
不足情報があればご質問いただけると幸甚です。

もし解決策がおわかりになる方いらっしゃいましたらお手数ですがご教授願います。

Comment: 書き忘れましたが【インストーラー作成時】
プロジェクト出力選択の時の構成(c):では　(アクティブ)　Release Any CPUをそれぞれ選択して作成しましたが同じ挙動でした。

Comment: 上記の件、自己解決しました。開発中、ローカルデータベースを作成するのにアプリ起動直後、データベースがないときはデータベースを作成するコードをかいていたのですが、それがデバック実行中はエラーにならなかったのに、インストールしたアプリ実行すると、そこでエラーになりアプリが止まっていたようです。お騒がせしました。

Comment: 差し支えなければ情報共有のために、(前後の流れ等を含む)どのようなコーディングや処理の箇所で、どのようなエラーが発生し、それをどのように解決したのか、といったことを自己回答してみてください。

Comment: デバッグ中とリリース後のアプリを実行するアカウントの権限の違いで、後者には SQL Server で DB を作成する権限がなかったということですかね？